# remove blank first line script

Tags: file, sed, find, grep

I have this script which is printing out the files that have the first line blank:

```
for f in `find . -regex ".*\.php"`; do 
  for t in head; do 
    $t -1 $f  |egrep '^[  ]*$' >/dev/null && echo "blank line at the $t of $f"; 
  done; 
done
```

How can I improve this to actually remove the blank line too, or at least copy all the files with the blank first line somewhere else.

I tried copying using this, which is good, because it copies preserving the directory structure, but it was copying every php file, and I needed to capture the postive output of the egrep and only copy those files.

```
rsync -R $f ../DavidSiteBlankFirst/
```

Comment: Are you sure, you don't just want to replace `^\s+\<\?` with `<?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use sed personally

```
find ./ -type f -regex '.*\.php' -exec sed -i -e '1{/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;}' '{}' \;
```

this finds all the regular files ending in .php and executes the sed command which works on the first line only and checks to see if its blank and deletes it if it is, other blank lines in the file remain unaffected.

Comment: sed: 1: "1{/^[[:blank:]]*$/d}": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: strange works for me on GNU sed version 4.2.1 try a semi-colon after the d command. I'll update the answer to include it.

Comment: This works now, although it created a duplicate file with -e appended to file name

Comment: the -i argument takes a suffix to backup the existing file. if there was no whitespace between the -i and -e then it will use -e as a suffix to create a backup.

Comment: I see. I just threw this at it to remove them find . -type f -name "*-e" -exec rm -f {} \;

Answer (score 1):

Just using `find` and `sed`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '1{/^\s*$/d;q;}' {} \;
```

---

The `-type f` option only find files, not that I expect you would name folders with a `.php` suffix but it's good practice. The use of `-regex '.*\.php'` is overkill and messier just using globbing `-name "*.php"`. Use find's `-exec` instead of a shell script, the `sed` script will operate on each matching file passed by `find`.

The `sed` script looks at the first line only `1` and applies the operations inside `{}` to that line. We check if the line is blank `/^\s*$/` if the line matches we delete `d` it and quit `q` the script so not to read all the other lines in the file. The `-i` option saves the change back to the file as the default behaviour of `sed` is to print to `stdout`. If you want back files making use `-i~` instead, this will create a backfile `file~` for `file`.

Comment: The solution was tested and works, what version of `sed` do you have? What platform are you on? What modifications did you make?

Comment: It's something to do with -i flag with sed on Mac

Comment: I tested on `Mac` and fixed the errors *(needed a trailing ;)* try now and let me know if you still see any.

Comment: Casserly-MacBookAir:TestFolder dave$ find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '1{/^\s*$/d;q;}' {} \;
sed: 1: "./index.php": invalid command code .

Comment: Still get the same error. Thanks for your input on this, peteches answer worked for me.