# error rendering a sitemap with laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem rendering a sitemap with laravel. 
Generated xml seems ok but when i try to call the url from chrome or firefox i got an error

```
 error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

In fact line 1 of the document is empty and xml declaration starts on line 2

Here is my code :

```
 return Response::view('sitemap.index', ['agences' => $agences])->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

i tried that syntax too :

```
 $xml = View::make('sitemap.index', ['agences' => $agences]);
 return Response::make($xml, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

That way i could do

```
 dd($xml->render());
```

and realize the string returned has no empty first line.
So i'm guessing Response::make is the one to blame but i really have no idea where to look from there

Comment: I suppose you already checked for whitespace at the beggining of the document?

Comment: Hi Adrenaxus, i even triple checked it .....

Comment: try setting `'Content-Type', 'text/xml'`

Comment: same thing happens ... but thanks anyway

Comment: I have a strong feeling that there's a whitespace OR line break hidden somewhere. Why would there be an empty line at the start otherwise? Also try to omit the php closing tag (`?>`). That might also create a whitespace.

Comment: Does the whitespace appear on ALL of your pages or only when you generate the XML?

Comment: No the empty first line does not appear when i generate json or html content. I used a blade template to generate the xml so laravel compiles it to a php coded view. I checked that file too in the laravel cache directory. No empty first line, no empty lines at all in fact, no whitespace at end of lines ... i don't know where to look. I think i 'm just gonna switch to a SimpleXMLElement for making it works

Comment: Ok i found it, answer is below.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm gonna post my own answer cause that was tricky and it costs me a day, the good thing is my knowledge of laravel has slightly increased.

So i had my xml sitemap beginning with an empty line, and that created an error on browser.
Xml was first generated using a blade template.
As it didn't work i decided to use [RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap)

But i had the same problem. So finally i decided to generate Xml myself again using SimpleXmlElement and it changes nothing.

At that point i begun to dig in Laravel internal's to see where that empty line could come from in the request lifecycle.

Basically my sitemap is very simple :

```
$urlset = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" /><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->');
datas = MyModel::All();
foreach($datas as $index=>$data){
// generate sitemap
}
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($urlset->asXML());
$dom->formatOutput = true;
//output xml
$xml = $dom->saveXML();
$response = Response::make($xml, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/xml']);
```

Just to test i decided to change the model i was requesting, and then my xml generated without that first empty line. 
So i decided to investigate the model itself and find the error. The model file just had an empty line before php opening tag.

Deleting that empty line has solved my problem ....

Comment: Thanks a lot this answer was so much helpful, I'd the same thing empty space in Routes.php, and I was testing twilio with closure rote.
thanks again

Comment: Most probably due to a php file starting with a blank line indeed!
Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14341815/237739) to easily find which file!